# How to import from multiple databases at once?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, recordset, multiple-databases

I need to import data into a new database.
The majority of it is stored in the database `dbo_Orders`, however i need to assign the data from it to the company that delivered the entry. This `companyID` is not stored in `dbo_Orders` but in `dbo_Delivery`. Luckily both databases note the `OrderID` so that i could compare them like a primary key (none of them have a primary key, im not responsible for database creation here, dont blame me please).

The main issue is that I also have to only import orders made by spefic companies stored in the array `companyIDs()`.
This means that I will need to:

1. Select all entries from `dbo_Delivery` that are in `companyIDs()`
2. Take their `OrderID`s and `CompanyID`s
3. Select all entries from `dbo_Orders` where the `OrderID` is equal to the ones that i got from `dbo_Delivery`
4. Import them into the new DB and connect them to the `CompanyID` that deliverd the order

Is there any way to do this without having to make a ***huge*** array of all `OrderID`s that i need to import. We are talking about 100.000 entries here.

Something like `SELECT * WHERE [dbo_Orders].OrderID = "OrderIDs that are from specific companies"`

(Again, im not responsible for the structure of these databases. It was my predecessor and i cannot change them for this task, so including `CompanyID` in `dbo_Orders` is not an option here)

Comment: The standard approach would be to import them into some sort of staging table without trying to do any 'logic' on them, then join on the records in that table.

Answer (score 0):

have you tryed a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT           *
FROM             dbo_Orders
LEFT JOIN        dbo_Delivery
ON               dbo_Orders.OrderID = dbo_Delivery.OrderID 
WHERE            CompanyID in (CompanyID1,CompanyID2,CompanyID3,CompanyID4,....)
```

instead of making a list of the orderID from the companies you want, in this way you only make a list with the company's ID.

Good Luck
Luis